# Numeric TextBox in DataGridView column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`. I want its 1st column or any desired column (which has `textboxes` in it) to be *`NUMERIC ONLY`*. I am currently using this code:

```
private void dataGridViewItems_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridViewItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewItems.Columns["itemID"].Index)
            {
                TextBox itemID = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (itemID != null)
                {
                    itemID.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(itemID_KeyPress);
                }
            }
        }

private void itemID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

This code works but the problem is that all the `textboxes` in all the columns are getting numeric only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself :)

Just removed the previous events in the starting of the function which resolved my issue.

```
private void dataGridViewItems_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(itemID_KeyPress);//This line of code resolved my issue
            if (dataGridViewItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewItems.Columns["itemID"].Index)
            {
                TextBox itemID = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (itemID != null)
                {
                    itemID.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(itemID_KeyPress);
                }
            }
        }

private void itemID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in a List all the numeric cells index.

Like this:

```
List<int> list_numeric_columns = new List<int>{ dataGridViewItems.Columns["itemID"].Index};
```

You add all the columns you need there.

Then, instead of doing this:

```
if (dataGridViewItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewItems.Columns["itemID"].Index)
```

You do this:

```
if (list_numeric_columns.Contains(dataGridViewItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex))
```

That should work. You will have to add the columns just once..

Hope thats helps

Comment: The problem is in the event itself, not in the condition. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use `EditingControlShowing` with `TextBox` → `Keypress Event`

```
   private void dataGridViewItems_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemID = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (dataGridViewItems.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex ==  1) //Where the ColumnIndex of your "itemID"
        {
            if (itemID != null)
            {
                itemID.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(itemID_KeyPress);
                itemID.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(itemID_KeyPress);
            }
        }
    }

    private void itemID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
            && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: If I register and immediately remove the KeyPress event, then what would be the point in registering it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Click the textbox that you want to be numeric only then in the properties click the "events" (looks like thunder) then look for the "keypress" then double click then type this:

```
if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
else
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

[image]