# DataGridviewCell prevent non-numeric input

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I have a `PreviewKeyDown` event in my grid and i want to let just numeric value and (0,2) decimal value.

```
private void dgvUser_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        colUser = dgvUser.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        rowUser = dgvUser.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewCell tc = dgvUser[colUser, rowUser];

        valueUser = Convert.ToDouble(tc.Value);//code breaks here


        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter && dgvUser.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2 && handledUser == true)
        {
            DragerClass.Dedektör.Dedektor_A1Set[Convert.ToInt32(dgvUser.Rows[rowUser].Cells[0].Value) - 1] = valueUser;
            BindUserGrid(userPagingUpdate[0], userPagingUpdate[1]);
            logValues(Convert.ToInt32(dgvUser.Rows[rowUser].Cells[0].Value) - 1);
            handledUser = false;
        }
    }
```

When i enter non numeric value code breaks in `valueUser = Convert.ToDouble(tc.Value);` line. how can i prevent that?

Comment: This might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542470/numeric-textbox-in-datagridview-column

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Double.TryParse` method:

```
if (Double.TryParse(tc.Value.ToString(), out valueUser))
{
   //success
}
else
{
   //fail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use a Try/Catch statement,

```
    try
    {
         valueUser = Convert.ToDouble(tc.Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        // if the above line throws an exception deal with it here.
    }
```

or you could use double.TryParse()

```
double valueUser;
bool isNumber = double.TryParse(tc.Value,out valueUser);
```

Comment: I have tried ur suggestion but that time i have another problem :( in a wrong input cell has 0.0 value and i lose old value.

Comment: I dont understand, you loose the old value? Save it before conversion `var oldValue = tc.Value` and then you follow it with the code you need?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to set the `DataGridViewCell.ValueType` that you use as a template for your column to `typeof(decimal)` this will create a `DataError Event` every time the user tries to input a value different to what you have specified. You can then handle that `DataError Event` to whatever you like.